how do I clone github repo ssh key to cli, i keep getting syntax error near unexpected token `newline`
I keep getting syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
I am using windows and git bash
I copied ssh key for GitHub repo
I was expecting to clone GitHub repo
I downloaded code editor
trying to connect GitHub repo to local environment
